# Space tree toggle functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, infovis, thejit, space-tree

I am working onspace tree provided on this link [Space Tree Animation](https://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example1.html).For the past 3 hours I am trying to add toggle functionality in this tree. For example if I click a node and all of its childrens are opened then it should collapse and vice versa.So in simple I want sort of toggle functionality.How can I acheive this?.Secondly when I click on one node it's sibblings get collapsed how can I stop this?.It's a bit complex for me to sort it out.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Docs/files/Visualizations/Spacetree-js.html check API dicumentation

Answer (score 2):

Check this:

https://github.com/rlopez0689/OrgChartJit

Feel free to contribute :)